# Display user what time (hh.mm.ss) he/she entered the website

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website on which I want to show the user the specific time (hh.mm.ss) when he/she loaded that website.

I suppose that I have to use

```
document.getElementById("entryTime").innerHTML =
```

but i am not sure of what exactly i shall use as the function to register and display that specific entry time.

(?maybe)
I read several threads and understand that I have to somehow take the time count (as in code below) and stop it immediately? But it doesn't look clean and functional.

```
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();

  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('entryTime').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}
startTime();
```

Any recommendations will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript will run when the page is loaded. All you need to do is get a timestamp which you can use. ES6 "string interpolation" or "template literals" are a nice way to build strings (which you did with string concatenation) read more about it here: [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var timestamp = new Date(); // get current timestamp from now

var element = document.querySelector('#entryTime')
element.innerHTML = `${timestamp.getHours()}:${timestamp.getMinutes()}:${timestamp.getSeconds()}`;
```

```html
<h1 id="entryTime"></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you! @caramba I have a small question. Is it generally possible to save this value once the page is reloaded?

Comment: @Pusher you could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (you can only save strings there so you need to convert it back to dateTime, but luckely it's easy)

Comment: I have been trying to do it, but i can't manage it to save in local storage. watched many tutorials, applied them to the case and it still doesn't work... is .toString() a correct way to turn into string? I was even trying to save it as id, but doesn't work

Comment: @Pusher ask a new question including what you have tried and what your expected result should look like.

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need:

```js
const date = new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
document.getElementById('entryTime').textContent = date
```

```html
<p id="entryTime"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you @Beki, works well! I have tried             **localStorage.setItem("date", date);

            var date = localStorage.getItem("date");** it saves time, but doesn't show it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a live display (w/ mili - seconds). The user can see the exact time they loaded the website. You can use this to understand the process of how each time unit is displayed, nonetheless a short method such as Date(), toLocaleString() would be preferred.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  let time = new Date();
  let hours = time.getHours();
  let minutes = time.getMinutes();
  let seconds = time.getSeconds();
  let amPm = "";

  if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
    amPm = "PM";
  } else if (hours == 0) {
    hours = 12;
    amPm = "AM";
  } else {
    amPm = "AM";
  }

  hours = hours > 10 ? hours : "0" + hours;
  minutes = minutes > 10 ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
  seconds = seconds > 10 ? seconds : "0" + seconds;

  document.getElementById(
    "entryTime"
  ).innerHTML = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds} ${amPm}`;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="entryTime"></div>
</body>
```